# writing to stdin and then moving the stream back 1 position

Tags: c, stdin, ncurses, seek

I have made a little program where I can move the cursor up,down,left and right.

now the last thing I want to add is the ability for the cursor to jump to the next or previous if it gets to the edge of the screen.

since I already implemented all kinds of checks to make sure I can move up and down within the key_up and key_down input handle parts I would like to 'borrow' these. I could of course rewrite them and reuse them in the key_left and key_right scenarios.

However it would be way shorter if I could just write to stdin and 'fake' user input as if key_up or key_down was pressed, and only have to change the x-position of the cursor.

so what I want something like this

```
putc(KEY_UP,stdin);fseek(stdin,-1, SEEK_CUR);
```

so on the next getch() it retrieves the character I put to stdin with putc!

I use ncurses for the entire program interface!

on Filipe suggestion I tried to do something with ungetc(), but it doesn't have the behavior I want.

here is a small test program, in theory it should print out infinite p's after the first character but it doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main () {
    int       input,i=0;

    initscr();
    start_color();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    raw();
    nonl();
    noecho();

    do {
        input=getch();
        if (i==24) {i=0;erase();}
        mvprintw(i,0,"%c --- %i",input,input);
        refresh();
        if (ungetc((unsigned char)'p', stdin)==EOF) {
            printw("    ERROR UNGETC");
        }
        else {printw("    SUCCES UNGETC");}
        ++i;
    } while (input!='q');
    endwin();
    exit(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ncurses, you're looking for `ungetch()`. From the manpage:

> The ungetch routine places ch back onto the input queue to be returned
>   by the next call to wgetch. There is just one input queue for all
>   windows.

The function prototype:

```
int ungetch(int ch);
```

It returns the integer `ERR` upon failure and an integer value other than `ERR` (`OK` in the case of `ungetch()`) upon successful completion.

**For future reference only**

If anyone reading this answer wants a simple way to push back characters onto a file stream, `ungetc()` is the correct approach. `ungetch()` is appropriate only for anyone using ncurses.

`ungetc()` pushes back one character into a given file stream:

```
int ungetc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

From the manpage:

> ungetc() pushes c back to stream, cast to unsigned char, where it is
>   available for subsequent read operations. Pushed-back characters will
>   be returned in reverse order; only one pushback is guaranteed.

You will want to call it with `stdin`, as in:

```
ungetc((unsigned char) KEY_UP, stdin);
```

It returns `c` on success, `EOF` on error. Bear in mind that it only guarantees one push back character; you can't call `ungetc()` twice and then expect that calling `getch()` twice gives you back the last 2 pushed characters.

Comment: that is exactly what I was look for. however it doesn't seem to work. I added a small example in my original post!

Comment: Did you pass it to `ungetc()` as `unsigned char`?

Comment: yes, tried with and without. the example is posted now. thx for the help :)

Comment: Hum... what's the code for `getch()`? This should work if you use `getchar()` or `getc()`. `getch()` may be doing some nasty stuff that mess around with `ungetc()`

Comment: its from the ncurses library, as far as I understood it it reads from stdin

Comment: @prgmjunkie See edited answer. You must use ncurses's own version, which is `ungetch()`. This is probably because ncruses keeps its own buffer.

Comment: it works with getc(stdin)! It would be really annoying for me to rewrite my entire code to use getc() instead of getch since special characters with getc are sometimes update 5 chars. I will look for a way to read from stdin with getch().

Comment: @prgmjunkie No, stop. Don't use `getc()`. It should work if you use `ungetch()` instead of `ungetc()`, because `ungetch()` is ncurses's own version of `ungetc()`. Try it. Interleaving `getc()` with ncurses `getch()` may give you weird errors.